# Crash when performing savedInstanceState.containsKey()

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

I get a crash when I use this code:

```
if (!savedInstanceState.containsKey("mybool")) {
    //  my code
}
```

My `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}
```

Elsewhere in my code:

```
savedInstanceState.putBoolean("mybool", true);
```

Comment: show your log will help other guys in finding your problem

Comment: Where do you put the boolean?

Comment: @MuratK. read my question. what do you mean?

Comment: @PhanDinhThai please redo the code it's simple, I don't have a PC with  me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`savedInstanceState` will be `null` first time activity launches.

`savedInstanceState` will **not** be `null` after activity is recreated (e.g. as a result of configuration change, system kill the process of your app).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
        // activity is being launched first time
    } else {
        // is called after configuration change or framework restore your app
    }
}
```

Comment: ill try that and let you know